# Cursor Not Returned Query if Execute SQL Statement with Return Value

Tags: sql-server, delphi, dbexpress

I have an issue when executing query bellow with DBExpress and Delphi XE. I need to get last identity id from executed query :

```
function TServerDBUtils.ExecuteQueryWithIdentity(ASQLConn: TSQLConnection): Integer;
var
  newSQLQuery: TSQLQuery;
begin
  Result := -1;  
  newSQLQuery := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    with newSQLQuery do
    begin
      SQLConnection := ASQLConn;

      SQL.Clear;
      SQL.Add('Insert into SampleTable(uomname) values(' + Quotedstr('bag') +')';

      SQL.Add('Select Scope_Identity()');
      Open;
      Result:= Fields[0].AsInteger;     
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(newSQLQuery);
  end;
end;
```

I get error "cursor not returned query". I have used same method before, using FireDac & Delphi XE5 and got no error. No, I'm wondering if "open" is not allowed to do such thing in DBExpress. What method I should use? (We have to use DBExpress in our project)
I've tried this :

```
function TServerDBUtils.ExecuteQueryWithIdentity(ASQLConn: TSQLConnection): Integer;
var
  newSQLQuery: TSQLQuery;
begin
  Result := -1;  
  newSQLQuery := TSQLQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    with newSQLQuery do
    begin
      SQLConnection := ASQLConn;

      SQL.Clear;
      SQL.Add('Insert into SampleTable(uomname) values(' + Quotedstr('bag') +')';
      ExecSQL;

      SQL.Clear;
      SQL.Add('Select Scope_Identity()');
      Open;
      Result:= Fields[0].AsInteger;     
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(newSQLQuery);
  end;
end;
```

And always got null values, maybe because different session.
Sorry for my bad english, and thanks in advance for any help.

Update :
It works if we used @@identity :

```
SQL.Add('Insert into SampleTable(uomname) values(' + Quotedstr('bag') +')';
ExecSQL;

SQL.Clear;
SQL.Add('Select @@Identity');
Open;
Result:= Fields[0].AsInteger;
```

But, there's problem as SQLServer told, that if there was a trigger on that table fired (on Insert), The return value is the last ID of table that trigger inserted.

Comment: Use a stored procedure, will make your life easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most elegant way on SQL-Server might be to use the
[OUTPUT Clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/us-en/library/ms177564.aspx)
which is not only capable to return one ID but all new genered one in case of a multipart insert.

```
INSERT into aTable (aField)
OUTPUT Inserted.ID 
Values ('SomeValue')
```

If you have got a trigger on your table you will have to define a destination table for your OUTPUT

```
DECLARE @tmp table (ID int)
INSERT into aTable (aField)
OUTPUT Inserted.ID into @tmp 
Values ('SomeValue')
Select * from @tmp
```

Another advice would be to use parameters instead of hard coded values.

With TSQLQuery adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` before the statement will prevent the `cursor not returned query` error an deliver the expected result:

```
begin
  SQLQuery1.SQL.text :='SET NOCOUNT ON'
                +#13#10'DECLARE @tmp table (ID int)'
                +#13#10'INSERT into aTable (aField)'
                +#13#10'OUTPUT Inserted.ID into @tmp'
                +#13#10'Values (:P)'
                +#13#10'Select * from @tmp';
  SQLQuery1.Params.ParamByName('P').Value := 'SomeText';
  SQLQuery1.Open;
  Showmessage(SQLQuery1.Fields[0].asString);
end;
```

Comment: Thank you ,Still the problem is TSQLQuery it self. We have to use TSQLQuery.Open to retrieve any return from query. But TSQLQuery.Open doesn't allow us to execute insert, update, etc. We'll get error "cursor not returned query". And TSQLQuery.ExecSQL can execute insert, update, etc but doesn't have any return value. If we used ExecSQL followed by Open, it's doesn't work because of different scope. CMIIW

Comment: Thank you very much, 'SET NOCOUNT ON' is the solution. We've tried in our SQL Server Connection Properties and make 'NO COUNT' checked = true. But it doesn't work. But when we use your solution : add 'SET NOCOUNT ON' before primary SQL then followed by Select scope_identity(), this method works. And we'll tried your advice too, we'll try adding output Inserted.ID and generate in our class.

Answer (score 3):

I use to do this using XE2 and SQL Server

```
with newSQLQuery do
try      
  SQLConnection := ASQLConn;
  SQL.Clear;
  SQL.Add('Insert into SampleTable(uomname) values(' + Quotedstr('bag') +')');
  ExecSQL;

  SQL.Clear;
  SQL.Add('Select Scope_Identity() as id');
  Open;

  if not Eof then
     Result := FieldByName('id').asInteger;
finally
  FreeAndNil(newSQLQuery);
end;
```

So, I introduce the as keyword on the second SQL statement. When I open the Query, just check for the field with name 'id' that was requested.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried your solution but the return value always 0. Maybe because ExecSQL and Open is the same session but different scope. So scope_identity() doesn't work. If we used the @@identity, we'll get the result because it will read any scope, but we'll get wrong result if there was a trigger within table that insert into other table.